# Как в дочернем классе изменить параметр переданный по ссылке (C#)

Tags: c#

Передаю в дочернее окно параметр по ссылке, по нажатию на кнопку параметр в родительском объекте должен изменится. Проблема в реализации дальше конструктора ссылку передать не удается. Как решить?

```
public partial class Authorization : Form
{
    int auth;

    public Authorization(ref int authorized)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = "Авторизация";
        auth = authorized;

    }

    private void buttonLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        auth = 10;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ссылочные переменные "завезли" в C# 7.0, но, к сожалению, они пока что могут быть только локальными, поле класса ссылочным не сделать, поэтому ваш вариант неработоспособен.

---

Вам нужно завести специальный класс, который будет содержать соответствующее свойство и хранить ссылку на экземпляр этого класса, например:

```
class AuthorizationObject
{
    public int Authorized { get; set; }
}
```

тогда, в форме авторизации:

```
public partial class Authorization : Form
{
    AuthorizationObject auth;

    public Authorization(AuthorizationObject authorizationObject)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = "Авторизация";
        auth = authorizationObject;
    }

    private void buttonLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        auth.AuthorizationObject = 10;        
    }
}
```

Ну а сам объект нужно создать и сохранить в переменную перед передачей его в конструктор формы:

```
authorizationObject = new AuthorizationObject();
var form = new Authorization(authorizationObject);
...
```

---

Другой, более правильный способ — создать метод, который будет отображать окно авторизации и возвращать результат:

```
public partial class Authorization : Form
{
    int auth;

    public Authorization()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = "Авторизация";
        auth = 0;
    }

    private void buttonLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        auth = 10;        
    }

    public static int ShowAuthorizationDialog()
    {
        var form = new Authorization();
        form.ShowDialog();
        return auth;
    }
}
```

Использовать как-то так:

```
int auth = Authorization.ShowAuthorizationDialog();
```

Comment: Ну это покамест, ссылочные поля ещё добавят. Но с ограничениями, а то я положу в поле ссылку на переменную из стека.

Comment: @VladD, добавят ли? В перспективе любая переменная из стека может быть использована в качестве источника для ссылочной. Как это предусмотреть?

Comment: Например, так: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types#ref-struct-type

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите, использовать механизм ссылок в C#, то следует понимать, что сейчас вы присваиваете **переменной** значение **ссылки**, это означает, что **вы создаете локальную копию значения** в переменной и при изменении значения переменной, значение от которой идет ссылка, не поменяется. Я бы вам порекомендовал использовать свойства, вот таким образом:

```
public partial class Authorization : Form
{
    public int Auth { get; set;} = 0;

    public Authorization()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = "Авторизация";
    }

    private void buttonLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Auth = 10;        
    }
}
```

А в функции вызова, следующее:

```
Authorization form = new Authorization();
from.Auth = то, что вы передавали в виде ссылки;
/* какой-то код */
int auth = form.Auth;
```